# Finding the number of positive integers that are less than 1000000

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How  many  positive  integers  less  than  $1,000,000$  have  exactly  one  digit  that  is  $8$  and  the product of this digit $(8)$ with the sum of other digits is between $49$ and $69$?

Been stuck on this problem and trying to come up with a pretty solution because I can't to seem to find one.

We figured out that this has six spots because it cannot have $7$ or else it would be greater than a million: $$\_ \space \_ \space\_ \space\_ \space\_ \space\_ \space$$

And there is always an 8 and not counted toward the sum: $$\_ \space \_ \space\_ \space\_ \space\_ \space 8 \space$$

This sum has to add to $7$ or $8$, becuase $49 \le (7\cdot8) \lor (8\cdot8) \le 69$.

An example of a valid way to find a sum: $$348000 \rightarrow (3+4)\cdot8 = 56$$

Can anyone help me to create a simple counting method to find all the integers?

Comment: Well, the product of $8$ with anything is a multiple of $8$. Since we want it to lie between $49$ and $69$ it must therefore be $56$ or $64$.  I'd just do each case separately.

Comment: How would I count that? I know I would add the cases together, but any hint to how I can count it?

Comment: Just think about it.  With $56$, say, you need the sum of the other digits to be $7$. So how many $7-$tuples of non-negative integers add to $7$?  (Note;  happily you don't have to worry about the fact that these are digits, not arbitrary integers, since we clearly can't have any summand $≥10$).

Comment: Have you heard of "[Stars-and-bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))"?

Comment: As an aside, be careful to correctly account for numbers comprised of two eights and the rest zeroes like $80080$ and so on

Comment: Start with $n$ digits, how many ways is it possible to create a sum of 7 or 8 with $n-1$ digits? How many ways to arrange 8 with $n$ digits?

Ex. Say $n=2$, clearly only 1 way to make 7, and 8 cannot appear twice. So either 78 or 87. 

Now with $n=3$ For a two digit number how many ways to add to 7 or 8?  If the 1st digit is 1, then ? What about if the first digit is 2?  Keep going on this process for all cases. Also keep in mind that 8 can go anywhere in this case. So once you've found how many ways to sum 7 or 8, multiply that by $n$, since there are n slots where 8 can go.

Comment: @JMoravitz, I have heard of Stars and Bars. Here would I assume that I have $8$ objects ($0-7$) for my first case and I have $5-1$ boxes because one is taken up by an $8$? Does that sound like it's on the right track?

Comment: @spectralblue too tedious.  Learn about stars-and-bars and it will save you a great deal of time.  @ DippyDog, Yes, perhaps., though I'm not entirely sure you know what objects you are distributing.  You talk about "*8 objects (0-7)*"... that sounds off to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The punchline is going to be that you first choose the location of the $8$ in the six slots in $6$ ways.

You then distribute $7$ units among the remaining five spots in $\binom{7+5-1}{5-1}$ ways for the case of the overall product being $8\times 7=56$ or distribute $8$ units among the remaining five spots in $\binom{8+5-1}{5-1}$ ways in the case of the product being $8\times 8 = 64$, as per [Stars-and-bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

We recognize that among the outcomes counted in that second case were some we did not want to, namely those where we had two $8$'s and the rest of the digits are $0$'s.  There are $\binom{6}{2}$ of these.  We had accidentally counted them twice when we wanted to count them none.

Our total is then:

$$6\times \left(\binom{7+5-1}{5-1}+\binom{8+5-1}{5-1}\right)-2\times \binom{6}{2}$$

Comment: Subtle, with interesting points.  You don't have to worry that no upper constraint on $x_1 + \cdots x_5 = 7$ (for example) is placed (e.g. where $x_k \leq 9$), because no solution will violate the constraint.  Further, since each solution is *variable-specific*, you don't have to worry that a collection of digits where one of the digits *repeats* will generate fewer solutions than a collection of digits with no repetitions.